# How can I refer to an already open eww buffer without knowing its current name?

Tags: buffers, eww

Say I open a new buffer by `eww-browse-url "emacs.stackexchange.com"`. Then, I navigate for a while, so the `eww-se` buffer updates its name to the current url. Same history for another buffer `eww-ew`, lets say by doing `eww-browse-url "emacswiki.org"`.

Then, I switch to another different buffer, loosing the pointer to the eww buffers, so that I don't know how to refer to them programmatically.

I wonder if there is a way to switch back to a given eww buffer (`eww-se`, for example), without
knowing its current name, or a way to check if this buffer is already open. Obviously, I don't want to go
visually through the list of all open buffers. Maybe labeling the buffer or something ...

So, how can I refer to an already eww open buffer without knowing its current name ?

Comment: Are you using eww as it is or have you added customization to rename its buffer? For me, eww buffer is always named `*eww*`.

Comment: Sure, I am renaming the buffer. My question is related to whether there exist some other way to refer to a buffer other that its name.

Comment: @csantosb Other than explicitly holding a reference to the buffer object somewhere, there is no way to refer to a buffer.  If there was, you wouldn't need names anymore…

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through [`(buffer-list)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-List.html#index-buffer_002dlist-2189) to find the buffer that interests you. For example, the following expression returns the list of buffers in Eww mode :

```
(cl-remove :test-not (lambda (buffer)
                       (with-current-buffer buffer
                         (eq major-mode 'eww-mode)))
  (buffer-list))
```

If you want to keep track of a specific buffer after it's created, store [it](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Current-Buffer.html#index-current_002dbuffer-2143) in a variable.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using [IBuffer](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode) you can filter by major mode.

Within IBuffer press `/m` and then enter `eww-mode` to only see your eww buffers.

Comment: I believe the question is about a way to "*refer to them programmatically*". Consider updating your answer to address that.